# Why do I see "per GB - next 450 TB / month of storage used" in the bill when the total S3 buckets size are only about 500 GB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, billing

I have several S3 buckets in my AWS account.

The total size of them is about 500GB.

Why do I see `per GB - next 450 TB / month of storage used` in my bill?

[image]

The total size of the buckets in the `APN1` region is below 1TB, which is far smaller than 50TB.

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192391/how-do-i-find-the-total-size-of-my-aws-s3-storage-bucket-or-folder) to use `aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://<bucket_name>` to calculate all the sizes of the buckets.

Here's [the article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/aws-usage-report-understand.html#aws-usage-report-understand-converting-byte-hours) that tells you how to convert usage byte-hours to billed GB-months.

Comment: Have you reviewed in cost explorer to give you a better breakdown of where its being used? Do you potentially have leftover multipart uploads?

Comment: Did you have any significant peaks in storage requirements over the course of the month? The command you used only yields a snapshot, but doesn't provide insight into past usage.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams. I don't have cost explorer permission. I'll contact the administrator to get more details about the bill.

Comment: Maybe it's versioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company use AWS service through [ecloudvalley](https://www.ecloudvalley.com/).

Ecloudvalley has an [AWS organization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html) that includes many AWS accounts.

I see `per GB - next 450 TB / month of storage used` because the total S3 disk space used by the AWS accounts under the AWS organization is more than 50TB.